# Actionbar back button not working in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am creating a android app where i need to put back navigation ,so that when user click on action bar's home button user should be moved to one screen back on my app.But action bar home button is not responding to click events.
Here is my code.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }
            @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        ActionBar actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


        return rootView;
    } }

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.home:
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing this from the `Activity`?

Comment: yes. but it's not responding.

Comment: Is your `Activity` extending `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity` or only `android.app.Activity`? If only `Activity` you should call `getActionBar()` and if `ActionBarActivity` you should call `getSupportActionBar()`

Comment: Also, in your `case R.id.home` it should actually be `android.R.id.home`

Comment: ok. Thank you. i have change case R.id.home to case android.R.id.home. now it's work. @hiphopdroid

Comment: But i don't understand why we used case android.R.id.home instead of case R.id.home ? @hiphopdroid

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
case android.R.id.home:
```

try to use this instead of `case R.id.home:`

Answer (score 4):

Use `android.R.id.home` instead of `R.id.home`

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```